# ASP NET how to add a condition to a model validation annotation?

Tags: asp.net, validation, annotations

I have a Password Confirmation functionality in my form. But if the user is already logged in, I hide the password and passwordConfirmation fields from that form.

When this form is submitted, if the browser stored any "password" field from the website, then my model is validating the Confirm Password, which results in an error.

How can I add a condition to this validation, so that it won't trigger if the user is already logged in.

```
    [Display(Name="Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match")]
    [RequiredIfEqual("LoggedIn", false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add condition for default `Compare` Attribute.

You can write an custom attribute for your requirement, in the attribute you can get `HttpContext.Current.Session["Login"] != null` and check your logic.

You can refer this to implement custom compare attribute

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780992/Asp-Net-MVC-Custom-Compare-Data-annotation-with-Cl